# Saving dataframe as XML in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val final_df = sqlContext.sql("select _xmlns, `md:Date`, `md:Creator`, struct(_ngr, _region, SetofValues) as Station from (select _xmlns, `md:Date`, `md:Creator`, _ngr, _region, struct(_dataType, _period, Value) as SetofValues  from (select _xmlns, `md:Date`, `md:Creator`, _ngr, _region, _dataType, _period, struct(_VALUE, _time) as Value from df_h a left outer join df_ds b on a.batchId = b.batchId left outer join df_dsv c on b.batchId = c.batchId left outer join df_nv d on c.batchId = d.batchId))"
final_df.repartition(1).write.format("xml").option("rowTag","NewTag").save(output_path)
```

Schema for above line is as below

```
root
 |-- _xmlns: string (nullable = true)
 |-- md:Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- md:Creator: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Station: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- _ngr: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _region: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- SetofValues: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _dataType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _period: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Value: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- _VALUE: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _time: string (nullable = true)
```

when I am trying to save dataframe as XML using above command getting XML file as below.

```
<ROWS>
<NewTag xmlns="testing">
    <md:Date>2016-10-30</md:Date>
    <md:Creator>USER_1</md:Creator>
    <Station ngr="123456" region="North East">
        <SetofValues dataType="Total" period="15 min">
            <Value 3.509" time="05:30:00"></Value>
        </SetofValues>
    </Station>
</NewTag>
<NewTag xmlns="testing">
    <md:Date>2016-10-30</md:Date>
    <md:Creator>USER_1</md:Creator>
    <Station ngr="123456" region="North East">
        <SetofValues dataType="Total" period="15 min">
            <Value 2.6" time="05:45:00"></Value>
        </SetofValues>
    </Station>
</NewTag>
<NewTag xmlns="testing">
    <md:Date>2016-10-30</md:Date>
    <md:Creator>USER_1</md:Creator>
    <Station ngr="123456" region="North East">
        <SetofValues dataType="Total" period="15 min">
            <Value 1.111" time="06:00:00"></Value>
        </SetofValues>
    </Station>
</NewTag>
</ROWS>
```

How to achieve below output. By creating array fro rows..

```
<NewTag xmlns="testing">
<md:Date>2016-10-30</md:Date>
<md:Creator>USER_1</md:Creator>
<Station ngr="123456" region="North East">
    <SetofValues dataType="Total" period="15 min">
        <Value time="05:30:00">3.509</Value>
        <Value time="05:45:00">2.6</Value>
        <Value time="06:00:00">1.111</Value>
    </SetofValues>
</Station>
</NewTag>
```

I am not able to convert different rows into list of array to achieve array in xml

Comment: Your data is not in the correct format itself. That is why it is printing like that. do a final_df.show and see it. Transform data properly, group it like you want, and it will save it.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand Could you help in converting  rows into array??

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but just in case anyone wonders your schema contains one Value for each Set of Values for each Station for each Root, something like...

```
Root  Station  Set  Value
Root  Station  Set  Value
Root  Station  Set  Value
Root  Station  Set  Value
```

If you want to have that output you need to reduce by key and make the "Value" an array.

So after the reduction by the three keys your dataframe would look like...

```
Root  Station  Set  [Value, Value, Value, ...]
```